# Mobile site presents: ERROR : -> No such file or directory

Tags: javascript, php, css, mobile

hope you're well, I am coding a basic Trading site and my main site works yet my mobile site gives me a No File error, I use a js script to redirect people to the mobile directory which just has a few things removed and some css changed.

https://Tom-croft.com

The site is the rleague part, to view as if you were on a mobile device in the dev thing (f12) and click the little phone.

I think its the Js thats wrong so here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "https://tom-croft.com/rleague/mobile/index.php";
}
</script>
```

This is in the head of my home.php and index.php on the desktop versionso you are redirected as you enter the site.

Any help is appreciated a lot :D

Comment: It's saying the `/rleague/mobile` directory doesn't exist... what's the directory structure of your website? Have you verified what the path to `mobile` is? Is `/rleague` some sort of app that might not let you refer to directories like that or has some sort of `.htaccess` or something that handles directories nested under `/rleague`? Maybe try moving `mobile` to the root of your website and see if `/mobile` works?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind people, it was a database error, I had my config from when I was hosting on xampp, although this is a funny error for a database connect file.